# How to stop clients from examining the source code in your library

Tags: c++, header-files

When writing a library in C++, we need to hide the implementation in the header file. But we need to include the source files in order to make the library work. But the users can easily find your source files in your library. So how do you hide the source files? What does the famous libraries such as boost do?

Comment: boost does not hide the source in any way. It is totally open.

Comment: Distribute library in binary form + headers? (Note: people can still possibly reverse engineer this) Otherwise impossible.

Comment: If you give them the source I do not see any way to hide it..

Comment: The thing is, most of the Boost libraries are *header-only*. It doesn't mean that the `.cpp` is hidden. It means that everything (including implementation) are in the `.hpp`s. So the implementation is visible through the headers in Boost case.

Comment: What's the use of hiding the implementaion if the client can easily look up your source files??

Comment: Don't give the client the code if you do not want them to look at it. Compile the code into a library and give them the headers. Make sure you compile it for the compiler that they will use since there are many incompatibilities between different compilers and even different versions of the same compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can you let the compiler know that when the client includes the header file, it needs to automactically hook up the .lib file?

Comment: In visual studio there is #pragma comment( lib, "mylibname" ) however this does not work for other compilers.

Comment: In boost, there is a tool that can "build" your boost libraries into couple of .lib files. Some programs using boost cannot compile without those .lib files. So how does boost let the compiler know that it needs to look up the .lib files?

Comment: In visual studio it uses the pragma I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide the source code in header files.  The only way is to put the code in your .cpp files so it can't be viewed.  Also, you can make the functions `inline` to ask the compiler to optimize them in this way if speed is a concern.

STL and boost ship with the source code so you can read it (but it's not easy to read because of the naming conventions they employ).

Comment: What's the use of hiding the implementation if the client can find your source files? I don't think I found any implementations in relevant to the main boost library in the source files, by the way.

Comment: @VictorPrograss Then you are looking in the wrong place. The full source code of boost is freely downloadable.

Comment: @VictorPrograss, that's the point.  There is no use in hiding the implementation as you're going to distribute template code in .hpp files.  The boost library .hpp file _is_ the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best off obfuscating the code, if you absolutely must distribute the source.

However, why do you not want your customers to see the source? If you feel like you're giving away too much, then charge them more for the source, and just provide a distributable library.

For obfuscators, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code